# Ratchet: Slider and YouTube

Tags: youtube, slider, ratchet

we're using Ratchet (embedded in a Typo3 project where the slideshow should contain (youtube-)videos and a pagination (points).

We tried to replace the ratchet slider with AnythingSlider and Cycle2, but ran into problems initializing those sliders, especially when using our "back"-button (realized simply by "history:back()").

Is there a way to extend the abilities of Ratchet regarding the features of the included slider or does anyone have a glue, if there's a plugin/external slideshow out there which meet our requirements?
Or are we simply missing an obvious triggering event?

Thanks in advance!